# Double variable in cell formula. What am I doing wrong here? Range("A2").Formula = "=A1+" & i

Tags: excel, vba

Tried googling that, but no luck.

Anyway, let's say I calculate some value of type double somewhere inside my code. Then I need to use this value in a cell formula. For whatever reason my approach does not seem to work, giving 1004.

```
Dim i As Double
i = 0.5

Range("A1").Value2 = 1
Range("A2").Formula = "=A1+" & i
```

What am I doing wrong here and why does it not work? It does work if you change to an integer value

```
Dim i As Double
i = 2
```

Btw, the code below executes as expected

```
Dim i As Double
i = 0.5

Range("A2").Formula = i
```

Whereas if you change the last line to

```
Range("A2").Formula = "=" & i
```

It returns 1004.

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it must have to do with decimal delimiter, may be your excel environment uses ","

try this:

```
Range("A2").Formula = "=A1+" & Replace(i, ",", ".")
```

Comment: Damn you are amazing. Simple solution for MS being silly here. Works like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering, what exactly had led you you to the conclusion of problem being in separators? As well as how is it that `formula = i` makes excel substitute dot for a comma in the output cell?

Comment: You are welcome 1) I have been brought there by my own excel environment... 2) ".formula=i" lacks the "=" part that makes it a real formula, without that part it's like ".Value=i" and therefore no formula evaluation is called

Comment: Ah, that explains. `.formula= "="` calls some procedure that checks whether the formula is correct hence the error. Cool. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depending on the local you're using, you will either have `,` or `.`.

Another solution is to change it in your Excel options:

[image: Excel Change local decimal separator]

Comment: Should work as well, but I'm afraid there could be a compatibility issue when a code is run on another machine, which does not have separators configured as above. Thank you though!

Comment: You're right. Might be programmatically changeable, though.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `.FormulaLocal` instead of `.Formula`. However it can cause new problems, for example with parameter separators in function calls.